# Scan operator with asynchronous code

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, rxjs, rxjs5

I normally use scan like this:

`Observable.interval(10).take(10).scan((acc, x) => acc.concat(x), []).subscribe...`

Now, in the first parameter of scan, instead of a synchronous method I want to pass a method that gets (acc, x) and returns Observable of new acc. (eg. a method that saves to dB and returns the saved object with info that comes from db, like revision number, which is then added in the accumulator).

I found the [mergeScan operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeScan) which seems to have exactly the signature I want, but I cant find any example and when I try it I get `Property 'mergeScan' does not exist on type Observable<number>`.

What I tried is this:

```
Observable.interval(10).take(10)
        .mergeScan((acc, x) => Observable.of(acc.concat(x)), [])
        .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

I'm using rxjs5 in Angular2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see this operator in the version 5.0.0-beta.6 of Rxjs.

Do you try to import the operator this way:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeScan';
```